# How to get matrix of pairwise distance with given ndarray of coordinates using solely numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have `point_coords` ndarray:

```
point_coord_x = np.array([np.random.randint(low=-100, high=100) for i in range(40)])
point_coord_y = np.array([np.random.randint(low=-100, high=100) for i in range(40)])
point_coords = np.array([point_coord_x, point_coord_y]).transpose()
```

It looks like:

```
point_coords
array([[  62,  -31],
       [  49,   33],
       [  -2,  -86],
       [ -29,   49],
        ...
```

I want to get a square matrix with distance between points.
How am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
>>> from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
>>> distance_matrix(point_coords, point_coords)
array([[  0.        , 149.21461054,  88.64536085, ...,  44.94441011,  24.73863375,  60.5309838 ],
       [149.21461054,   0.        , 122.64175472, ..., 136.47344064, 163.60012225, 201.07958623],
       [ 88.64536085, 122.64175472,   0.        , ...,  45.01110974, 113.35784049, 147.2752525 ],
       ...,
       [ 44.94441011, 136.47344064,  45.01110974, ...,   0.        ,  69.57010852, 102.3132445 ],
       [ 24.73863375, 163.60012225, 113.35784049, ...,  69.57010852,   0.        ,  38.62641583],
       [ 60.5309838 , 201.07958623, 147.2752525 , ..., 102.3132445 ,  38.62641583,   0.        ]])
```

If only numpy is to be used:

```py
np.linalg.norm(point_coords[:, None, :] - point_coords[None, :, :], axis=-1)
```

Comment: I want an implementation using only numpy

Comment: I have updated my answer. Is there any reason for this constraint?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using solely *Numpy*:

Compute **deltas** by each coordinate (square matrices):

```
dx = point_coord_x[:, np.newaxis] - point_coord_x[np.newaxis, :]
dy = point_coord_y[:, np.newaxis] - point_coord_y[np.newaxis, :]
```

Then compute the **distance** array from these deltas:

```
result = np.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2)
```